# how to enable button by checking 3 checkbox?

Tags: javascript

This app is using Apache Cordova jquery for my project sponsor and they wanted their users to check the checkboxes before being able to carry on to the next page. But I am unable to come up with a javascript function for it, as I have read up on various questions within StackOverflow on how to check multiple checkboxes and enabling the button. So how do I go about this?

Below is my HTML of my checkbox and button.

```
    <div class="nd2-card">
                    <p align="center">Collection Date</p>
                    <p align="center">To place order 3 working days in advance. Last day of pick up is on 7 Dec 2018.</p>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-collectiondate" id="checkbox-collectiondate">
                    <label for="checkbox-collectiondate">Noted</label>
                </div>

                <div class="nd2-card">
                    <p align="center">Please note</p>
                    <p align="center">Full payment is to be made by the following working day at Sugarloaf between 10.30 am to 1.30 pm after you have received a confirmation email from us.</p>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-payment" id="checkbox-payment">
                    <label for="checkbox-payment">Noted</label>
                </div>

                <div class="nd2-card">
                    <p align="center">Please bring along the printed receipt to collect your orders from 13 Nov to 7 Dec 2018 between 10.30 am to 2 pm at Sugarloaf.</p>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-receipt" id="checkbox-receipt">
                    <label for="checkbox-receipt">Noted</label>
                </div>

                <input type="button" class="ui-btn ui-btn-raised clr-primary" id="btnNextPage2" value="Next" disabled />
```

Comment: Since you already read various questions, can you also add the codes that you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkCheckbox(){
   if(document.getElementsByName("checkbox-collectiondate")[0].checked && document.getElementsByName("checkbox-payment")[0].checked && document.getElementsByName("checkbox-receipt")[0].checked){
    document.getElementById("btnNextPage2").disabled = false;
   }else{
    document.getElementById("btnNextPage2").disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nd2-card">
  <p align="center">Collection Date</p>
  <p align="center">To place order 3 working days in advance. Last day of pick up is on 7 Dec 2018.</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-collectiondate" id="checkbox-collectiondate" onclick="checkCheckbox();">
  <label for="checkbox-collectiondate">Noted</label>
</div>

<div class="nd2-card">
  <p align="center">Please note</p>
  <p align="center">Full payment is to be made by the following working day at Sugarloaf between 10.30 am to 1.30 pm after you have received a confirmation email from us.</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-payment" id="checkbox-payment" onclick="checkCheckbox();">
  <label for="checkbox-payment">Noted</label>
</div>

<div class="nd2-card">
  <p align="center">Please bring along the printed receipt to collect your orders from 13 Nov to 7 Dec 2018 between 10.30 am to 2 pm at Sugarloaf.</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-receipt" id="checkbox-receipt" onclick="checkCheckbox();">
  <label for="checkbox-receipt">Noted</label>
</div>

<input type="button" class="ui-btn ui-btn-raised clr-primary" id="btnNextPage2" value="Next" disabled />
```

This is a simple way to enable the button if all the checkbox are checked.

Here `getElementsByName` returns a collection of all checkbox elements in the document with the specified name. so if you have a single checkbox then use [0] to get the checked property.

Comment: Better make the function more dynamic. Otherwise, either on every checkbox name change or adding additional checkbox on the page, the function will stop work.

Comment: Agreed... But with respect to OP's html snippet its a simple approach.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make your custom JS function for that:

```
<script>
function checkBoxStatus() {
    var allBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    var checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    if (checkedBoxes.length == allBoxes.length)
            ? document.getElementById('btnNextPage2').disabled = false
            : document.getElementById('btnNextPage2').disabled = true;
}
</script>
```

And call it via `onclick` event in every checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-collectiondate" id="checkbox-collectiondate" onclick="checkBoxStatus()">
```

When all checkboxes are checked (no matter how many they are on the page), the button will become enabled and vice versa.